# Context Menu Insert disabled - Excel 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2013, context-menu

I have Excel 2013 on Windows 7. When I right click on a row the Context Menu appears. However the strange thing I notice is that the Insert option is simply disabled by Excel on the Context Menu. See the screenshot.

There are no merged cells or anything like that just plain numbers in a column and that’s it. There’s nothing to the right of the sheet or anything else that would prevent Excel from allowing to Insert, just in case.

The Insert option on the ribbon works fine as expected though. It’s disabled only on the Context Menu.
I have no clue what causes Excel to disable Insert on Context Menu and is there any setting or way to get it working again or is this the default behavior?

[image: Insert Disabled on context menu]

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Close all open Excel workbooks
2. In Windows Explorer, go to directory `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel"`
3. Find the file `Excel15.xlb`
4. Rename this file to:  `Excel15.old`